# iOS developers - Support For Devices of Different Versions

Tags: ios, xcode

I was wondering what others do in the ways of testing for multiple iOS versions. 
Do you use multiple iPhones / iPads running different iOS versions? 
Do you rely only on the simulator? Is there an easy way to swap versions out on a device?

Everything I'm finding is telling me that my iPhones at 5.x cant be downgraded to 4, and I was just wondering how others deal with this sort of thing

Thanks

Comment: If you want to downgrade, try this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNcTMV4ELRo

Comment: Thanks, But this leaves me in a situation where I have to tether boot from red snow, and that is a complete pain. I am looking for a more permanent solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest buying one old device to run 3.1.3 (they're extremely cheap on ebay or similar) and just test on that and the newest version. If an app runs on iOS 3.x and 5.x, it will basically always work on 4.x.

Comment: This makes sense, and is a good idea. My concern here, however, is the vast amount of class deprecation between 3 and 4, and 4 and 5. The project I'm on requires methods that are 4.2 and higher, so we don't currently support 3. I wonder how difficult it would be to find a device that is running 4.2 currently.

Comment: iPhone 3Gs (plural, not 3GS) are on 4.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

Start by developing on the oldest device/IPSW you have at hand. If necessary, downgrade. When your app builds and runs correctly on, say, an iPhone 3G[S] on 3.2.1, you can move on to testing on newer hardware/software.

Comment: Thanks, Cyrille. The reason I ask is that all i currently have are iOS 5 and above phones, and I'm needing a 4. I had one at 4 but at one point it went into recovery mode and I was forced to upgrade to get it back on. The downgrade process is the part im having problems with at this point.

Comment: Actually you can simply borrow an iOS 4 phone from someone you know !

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I test on the newest firmware and start downgrading my device and testing again on each. It's kind of tedious, but it works for me. There are plenty of tutorials online on how to downgrade your firmware by downloading the ipsw and then restoring from it. It works well, and I wouldn't suggest testing purely on the simulator. Some older methods may be deprecated and you would want to switch those out. You can also switch the deployment target so you can build it on an older iOS version.

Comment: Can you link me to a place where I can see how to properly downgrade? I've tried it through iTunes and Organizer in Xcode with no luck, as it tells me the older firmware is not supported (Yes, I have checked to make sure im using the right version / carrier).

Comment: Well you can't use iTunes to downgrade without a lower ipsw to restore it to. Here is a good tutorial on how to downgrade your iPhone: http://www.ehow.com/how_2214485_downgrade-iphone-firmware.html

Answer (score 0):

I keep as many devices as I can in the oldest OS I can, unless I already dropped support for a too-old version (e.g., 3.1.3).

Last time I checked (5 minutes ago), it is impossible to downgrade (even with jailbreak) unless you have saved the proper "SHSH Blob" corresponding to the OS version you want to downgrade to, specific to your device.